# How configure Csp in Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, content-security-policy, nuxtjs3

How do you configure your CSP on Nuxt 3 ?
It's the first time i deploy an app online and i'm a bit confused.
I try with the module Nuxt/security, it's working but i don't really know how to configure.
Is it ok to let 'unsafe-inline' in 'style-src' ? Or 'script-src-attr': ["'none'"],

I read the doc but i don't really know what it's ok or not

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to run Nuxt 3 in production without allowing `script-src 'unsafe-inline';` and `style-src 'unsafe-inline';` in your `Content-Security-Policy` header.

For reference: The status is tracked in this GitHub discussion https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/4836.

Comment: Transferred discussion: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/15963